# Tengo un problema al asociar una variable a una sentencia Mysql

Tags: mysql, python, pyqt

Tengo dos combobox. Uno asociado al otro y los valores están dentro de una tabla Mysql, todo eso está bien.

Cuando corro lo siguiente lo hace bien

```
non = "13"
    sql = "SELECT idorder,customer FROM order WHERE customer="+non+""
```

Pero en este caso no. Sin embargo, el currentdata del combobox si está bien y arroja el número "13".

```
non = str(self.comboBox.currentData())
    sql = "SELECT idorder,customer FROM order WHERE customer="+non+""
```

Me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

Luego cambié las comillas. No me sale error pero el segundo comboBox ya no muestra ninguna lista.

```
non = str(self.comboBox.currentData())
sql = "SELECT idorder,customer FROM order WHERE customer='+non+'"
```

Este es un ejemplo al que he tomado como referencia y que ha funcionado correctamente pero en QlineEdit:

```
def ruc(self):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    non = str(self.comboBox.currentData())   
    sql = "SELECT numdoc FROM customer WHERE idcustomer="+non+""
    data = cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchone()
    for x in result:
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(str(x))
```

Y este este es todo el código que genera error

```
def combid(self):
    cur = conn.cursor()  
    non = str(self.comboBox.currentData())
    sql = "SELECT idorder,customer FROM order WHERE customer="+non+""
    data = cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    for x,y in result:
        self.comboBox_7.addItem(str(x),y)
```

ERROR:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'where clause'")
```

Comment: Gracias. Haciendo lo que usted dice ya no me sale error pero el segundo ComboBox ya no muestra ninguna lista. Ni aunque coloque "13" como en el primer ejemplo. Puse dos comillas porque ya lo había usado antes y no tuve problemas, pero en ese caso no era comboBox sino QlineEdit.@Excorpion

Comment: Si no le pongo str, me sale: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: @Excorpion , pues lo mismo. He subido un ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Hola, te sale el error, por lo que decía Excorpio. Tienes puesto el non sin que en la query salga como string (tiene que aparecer entre comillas). por lo que para que sea más sencillo, modifica la línea de sql por esta:
sql = "SELECT idorder,customer FROM order WHERE customer= '"+non+"'"
Parece la misma, pero he puesto una comilla simple dentro del encomillado de la clausula where y al final en el caracter vacío. Prueba con esto.

Comment: @PedrojaDoime Hola. Poniéndola esa comilla no sale error, pero el Segundo ComboBox ya no despliega el drop-Down. Pero si reemplazo toda la variable por 13 (que es uno de los valores de la condición) si corre. non = str(self.comboBox.currentData()) ....lo reemplazo por...non = "13"

Comment: Hola @johnnypk, has debuggeado para ver qué aparece en non = str(self.comboBox.currentData()), por experiencia, primero haz la query normal y mira los datos que te tienen que salir. Después debuggea y mira el valor del string non y de la query para ver que es igual a la que tu tienes hecha. No se con qué editor estás... pero pon un punto de interrupción en non y sql para ver el valor. Y que ese valor es el que tu quieres. a las malas imprime por pantalla las variables con un print y comprueba.

Comment: @PedrojaDoime He vuelto a intentar con la comilla y ahora sí corre. Lo he adjuntado al posteo original. Gracias

Comment: La soluciones van en el campo respuesta...

Comment: def combid(self):
        cur = conn.cursor()  
        non = str(self.comboBox.currentData())
        sql = "SELECT idorder,customerFROM order WHERE customer='"+non+"'"
        data = cur.execute(sql)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        for x,y in result:
            self.comboBox_7.clear()
            self.comboBox_7.addItem(str(x),y)